# Is there any advantage to checking for nil explicitly before making a selector call?

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance

I have seen code like this:

`if (myObject && [myObject mySelector]) ...`

I have heard that this prevents unnecessary selector lookup and a method call to send the selector message to an object pointer which is found to be nil at runtime.

However, I thought that a core principle of objective-C is that all selector calls to nil objects return nil, and so I expected this is optimized pretty well in terms of the compiler.

Does anyone know if there is truly any advantage of this pattern, in terms of performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know if there is truly any advantage of this pattern, in terms of performance?

**Standard Answer:** In all probability indistinguishable performance

**Real Answer:** One takes more instructions and jumps, there will be some performance difference and you *will* know if it is an important difference if you are writing the type of code where it matters – or else you wouldn't be writing that sort of code!

**I'm Just Curious Answer:** Curiosity is good, keep being curious! Write a very simple program using the standard Xcode template. First add a class `MyObject` with a method `mySelector`, return type `long`, which returns `1L` to the `AppDelegate.m` file.

Now inside the `AppDelegate` implementation write a small test method, something like:

```
- (int) test:(MyObject *)myObject
{
   if (myObject && [myObject mySelector])
      return 42;
   else
      return 24;
}
```

and then in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` add some code to call `test` passing both `nil` and an instance of `MyObject` and `NSLog` the return value.

Run it.

Now go to **Product -> Perform Action -> Assemble "AppDelegate.m". This will produce a list of the generated assembly language. At the bottom of this listing is a menu which allows you to select the type of build and hence how optimised the assembly code is; "Running" has little optimisation and is what is used while developing and debugging, "Archiving" shows the optimised code produced when building the final app.

If you look at the assembly (don't worry if you don't know x86 code the instruction names suggest their meaning) you will see that the initial test for `nil` is two instructions: compare & jump (to code for the else branch). After that there is the code for the message call: load the arguments, being `myObject` and the selector, into register, a call to `objc_msgSend`, and then a compare & jump to test its return value.

You can't see what `objc_msgSend` does as that is not your code. To discover that: put a breakpoint on the `if` and then run. When it stops open up the Assistant Editor and set it to show the disassembly – you'll now have Objective-C code in the left panel and the matching assembly code in the right panel.

Below these two panels are the debugging controls, if you mouse over them and pausing tooltips will pop up explains what each one does. Find "Step into" and hold down the control key and click, as the tooltip says this is "Step into instruction" and will step through the code an instruction, rather than an Objective-C source line, at a time. Repeat the control+click until the right panel shows you've stepped into `objc_msgSend`.

Now look at the `objc_msgSend` assembly and you will see it starts with a compare & jump for `nil`, and if you follow where the jump goes there are instructions to clear four register and then return.

So without the initial `nil` test in the `if` the code will load two argument register, jump to `objc_msgSend`, compare, test, clear 4 registers, and return to your code which then does the compare & jump on the returned value.

This is clearly more instructions **in the `nil` case**.

**However** non-`nil` cases pay for a compare & jump in the `if` which are unnecessary... So "which is better performance wise" is going to depend on the statistical distribution of `nil` and non-`nil` values, which is dependant on the code... And remember that modern machines execute millions of instructions per second, and have things like branch predication and caches to keep execution going fast even when the code is jumping about...

Hopefully by now your curiosity has led you to understand the "Standard Answer" above, and given you a hint at the sort of code and application areas where it might make a practical difference performance-wise.

So include the initial test if you think it clarifies the purpose of the code, don't otherwise. Your code might run faster or slower but you won't notice either way unless counting nanoseconds make a difference in your application area.

Stay curious!

Answer (score 0):

Other than as a hint for future developers that `nil` is acceptable there, it serves no purpose. I would expect the code to bail before any selector lookup happens.